# Are the Microsoft courses worth while doing?

Tags: untagged

What are your thoughts on the Microsoft courses – things like the MCSE, MCSA etc

Answer (score 4):

As an employer I regard them as helpful but not necessarily essential.

For a more junior person looking to get into (say) the sysadmin field I regard them as a good grounding in many of the essential skills and a very good place to start.  And of two similar candidates, I'd probably favour someone with a MCSE over someone without.  But there's also no substitute for a decent interview with a number of different technical questions to examine their knowledge and problem-solving skills.

Once you're looking for a more experienced sysadmin, experience and attitude become more important than qualifications IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

There a starting point, and a good thing to have, but if an employer is worth their salt, they are not going to employ you based on these qualifications, at least for a non entry level position, they will want to see experience as well.

I've know engineers who had reams of qualifications, but when it came to getting them to do real work, they didn't have a clue.

So by all means go for it, they look good on your CV, and might help you get your foot in the door and get an interview, but don't forget how much practical experience is worth. If you can get your MCSE while on the job, thats even better!

Answer (score 3):

Haven't they scrapped MCSE? I think they have for new products...check out http://www.microsoft.com/learning/mcp/newgen/default.mspx.

Comment: The original question and tags should be amended to reflect the current certification names.  The MCSE and MCSD names are outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The courses are a great starting point if you know nothing or to help validate that the knowledge you have is up to the minimum required standard to pass the certification exams.

However nothing beats experience and work ethic.  So get as much good experience as possible and learn the art of being a system administrator.  Some good skills to have would be to good communication and inter personal skills, problem solving and being able to work under pressure because no matter how good you are there will be times when this will be invaluable.